# Get independent audio information about the current device in use

Tags: bash, shell-script, drivers, audio

I need a reliable way to get audio information from a device in use and check if It's muted or not. It has to be the device that plays audio.

With a reliable way I mean in a way that is audio driver independent.
I already tried different things with amixer but I always have to change the command in order for it to work on multiple devices.

Here an example that would output `on` or `off` whether the Master device is muted or not:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $6 }' <(amixer sget Master)
```

The problem is that this works on my Laptop, but not on my main PC where I use pulseaudio with a USB headset, there I would have to use this slightly altered bit of code:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $6 }' <(amixer sget -c 1 PCM)
```

Not only do I need to specify which sound card I'm using, but also the device name(?) which is called PCM instead of Master, but I now have to use a completely different formatting option since the output is not completely different.

Now again, is there a better and more reliable way to get information about the audio device in use?

Comment: Have you considered writing a shell script or function that runs your `amixer` command, and customising it for each machine?   Call it, say, `get-mute-status` (and save it somewhere in your $PATH, e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin`) and have it return "on" or "off" no matter what it had to do to get that information.   Or write just one script and have it do different things depending on the output of `hostname -s` for the machine it's running on.

Comment: @cas Thats exactly what I'm doing now and what I don't want to do. Eventually this script is going to run on multiple machines without me ever interacting with them.